# Shift multiple column values to the right depending on some column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a Temporary table that has a column and value like this:

1st example

```
COL001  COL002  COL003  COL004  COL005  COL006  COL007  COL008  COL009  COL010
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
aa      bb      cc      dd       ee     *YY*    ff      gg      hh      ii
```

2nd example:

```
COL001  COL002  COL003  COL004  COL005  COL006  COL007  COL008  COL009  COL010
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
aa      bb      *YY*    ff     gg       hh      ii      jj      kk      ll
```

it should look like:

```
COL001  COL002  COL003  COL004  COL005  COL006  COL007  COL008  COL009  COL010
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
aa      bb                              *YY*    ff      gg      hh      ii
```

As you can see in the 1st sample `YY` is in `COL006`.

The data is not fixed in the columns.

When `COL003`, `COL004` and `COL005` are empty, the `YY` will shift to `COL003` and all remaining column will follow also.[2nd Sample]

All I want to happen is to fix the `YY` to `COL006` and all remaining columns and NULL the `COL003`, `COL004` and `COL005`.

Incoming data come from a text file and imported by windows-scripts that is managed by other team:

Sample1

aa|bb|cc|dd|ee|YY|ff|gg|hh|ii ----> upto 80 columns

Sample2

aa|bb|YY|ff|gg|hh|ii|jj|kk|ll ----> upto 80 columns

Comment: Is first row a header or actual output?

Comment: it is a column header.

Comment: Why don't you normalize these data? Than you wouldn't ask that question at all.

Comment: We are just receiving these information. The data coming from them is not fixed.

Comment: @sccydd, it cannot be solved as you lost mappings between column value and column name. All that you can find is the number of loses by counting "|" and comparing with expected number of columns

Comment: If you have "||" in case of missed value, it's solvable

Comment: add your coming sample data in the question

Comment: @Ali786 done adding some info about the incoming data file.

Comment: What clue do you have that the empty values should be inserted at column three and not somewhere else? From what you have provided there is no way to know where the blank columns should be. Or are you sure that when you have "YY" in COL003, it always means there are exactly 3 empty columns to be shifted? And is this true whereever "YY" occurs?

Comment: @trincot, My KeyPoint is the "YY" value as it is fixed and it should be on COL006. if "YY" is not on COL006 Then I should check on COL003, COL004 and COL005 to shift the values to right to align the "YY" to COL006.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLSplitString [SQL split function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-t-sql-split-function.aspx) to split data from its original format like "aa|bb|cc|dd|ee|YY|ff|gg|hh|ii" 
The referred split function has a parameter enabling programmer to eliminate empty or null values from the list and returned list has also an auto number field
So finally you will have ColumnNumber, ColumnValue in tabular format

Here is how you can use it

```
   --create table strList(id int, string nvarchar(max))
declare @str nvarchar(max) = 'aa|bb|cc||dd|ee||YY|ff|gg|hh|ii|'
insert into strList select 101,@str
set @str = 'aa|bb|YY|ff|gg|hh|ii|jj|kk|ll'
insert into strList select 102,@str

select 
    id, 
    MAX(col01) col01,
    MAX(col02) col02,
    MAX(col09) col09,
    MAX(col10) col10
from (
select 
    strList.id,
    case when s.id = 1 then val end as Col01,
    case when s.id = 2 then val end as Col02,
    case when s.id = 9 then val end as Col09,
    case when s.id = 10 then val end as Col10
from strList
cross apply dbo.SQLSplitString(string,'|',1,0) s
) t
group by id
```

[image]
I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, Will try this.

Answer (score 0):

If this shift is always triggered by one specific "YY" value in one of columns `col003`, `col004` or `col005`, with the result that `null` values are injected so that the "YY" is moved to the 6th column, then you could do this as follows (simplifying to 8 columns):

```
select col001, col002, col003, col004, col005, col006, col007, col008
from   mytable
where  "YY" not in (col003, col004, col005)
union all
select col001, col002, null,   col003, col004, col005, col006, col007
from   mytable
where  col005 = "YY"
union all
select col001, col002, null,   null,   col003, col004, col005, col006
from   mytable
where  col004 = "YY"
union all
select col001, col002, null,   null,   null,   col003, col004, col005
from   mytable
where  col003 = "YY"
order by col001
```

The `order by` should be adjusted (if you need a certain order). The `union all` construct will not keep the records in the original order -- at least it is not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks, Will try it.